# Man muss sicher auch die Kommandos auswendig können

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Why did we use *können* instead of *werden* or *sind*?

I believe it to be

> You should also be or become good with memorizing the details

And why in some sentences we use *müssen* and *können* without using any other verb?

Comment: *Details* kann man nicht mit *Kommandos* übersetzen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate in this sentence is **müssen**, which is a modal verb. It takes another verb in infinitive form as the action someone **has to** do. This second verb loses its auxiliary function (if it is not stacked with another infinitive):

> Sie muss da **sein**.

*She has **to be** there.*

> Er muss besser **werden**.

*He has **to become** better.*

**Können** is just another verb. It also loses its modal verb function.

> Er muss etwas **können**.

*"He has **to can** something."*

*He has **to be able to do** something.*

In English, *to can* is a very special verb which has lost almost all of its forms, so it has to replaced by *be able to do* here.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe !

Answer (score 4):

The answer is quite simple:

The word "auswendig" is not just an (adjective used as) adverb here but it belongs to a fixed expression itself:

"Etwas auswendig können" means: To know something by heart.

While the verb "etwas können" is normally used with another verb (infinitive) the term "etwas auswendig können" may be used with a verb or with something that can be learned (like a text, a book, a song ...) without a verb.

(Example: "*Ich kann den Text auswendig.*")

Comment: Thanks alot , i thought auswendig here came as an adjective besides i thought können always means to can

Answer (score 2):

"Etwas auswendig können" means to have memorized something, see https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/auswendig

The whole sentence means

> You certainly have to have memorized the commands as well.